# iOS Swift Realm Encryption and Sync with server

Tags: ios, swift, realm

I used this configuration code for **Realm Encryption**

```
let configuration = Realm.Configuration(encryptionKey: "key" as Data)

let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
```

I used this configuration code for **Realm Sync with server**

```
let configuration = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: syncServerURL))

let realm = try! Realm(configuration: configuration)
```

How we can do both Encryption and Sync with server using Realm?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The [`Realm.Configuration` initializer can accept multiple arguments](https://realm.io/docs/swift/latest/api/Classes/Realm/Configuration.html#/s:FVC10RealmSwift5Realm13ConfigurationcFT7fileURLGSqV10Foundation3URL_18inMemoryIdentifierGSqSS_17syncConfigurationGSqVS_17SyncConfiguration_13encryptionKeyGSqVS2_4Data_8readOnlySb13schemaVersionVs6UInt6414migrationBlockGSqFTCS_9MigrationS6__T__28deleteRealmIfMigrationNeededSb21shouldCompactOnLaunchGSqFTSiSi_Sb_11objectTypesGSqGSaMCS_6Object___S1_) if you'd like to specify multiple aspects of the configuration:

```
let config = Realm.Configuration(syncConfiguration: SyncConfiguration(user: user, realmURL: syncServerURL),
                                 encryptionKey: theKey)
```

Comment: Thanks for helping. Can SyncConfiguration be enabled or disabled?.

Comment: I'm not sure what it would mean to disable a configuration?

Comment: In some cases, I want to store the data only locally and not sync to the server? How do I achieve this?

Comment: Create and use two separate configurations, one with a sync configuration and one without.

Comment: Consider this scenario. Suppose I create some data without sync, it is saved locally. However, if I turn on sync(different configuration), the previously created data(locally) is not synced to the server? How to sync already saved data? Thanks for helping.

Comment: That's an entirely new question. Please mark my answer as accepted if it addressed your initial question and post a new question.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/145676/discussion-between-jeyachandran-and-bdash).

Comment: You're asking new questions that are only loosely related to your original question. You'd be much better served by posting a new question.

Comment: Added a new question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44324038/ios-swift-realm-sync-issue